# How to create a gradient "plusminus" color bar in R?

Tags: r, image, image-processing, color-scheme, colorbar

I am working on image processing in R. I have written a function in R which reads a text file and generates a color map using the coordinate information and intensity values for each co-ordiante within that file. To represent these images I am using the rainbow color scheme at the moment. However, I want to represent the images using a plus minus color scheme. Meaning, I need a color scheme with neutral central color (black), diverging either side to warm colors (red) for positive values, and cold colours for negative ones (blue). I tried to do this using the colorRamp package but somehow I am unable to get this color scheme. Can anyone help?

[image]

Code after implementing the suggestion:

```
levelplot(t(m), scales=list(tick.number=0), xlab=" ", ylab=" ",    
colorkey=list(at=as.numeric(factor(c(seq(from=range[1], to=range[2],  
by=.1)))),labels=as.character(c( "327.1", "327.2", "327.3", "327.4", "327.5", "327.6",
"327.7", "327.8", "327.9"))),col.regions = two.colors(n=256, start='red', end='blue',     
middle='black'), main=main)
```

range[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSMbn.jpg) = 327.1
range[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tQDA.png) = 327.9

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In package `fields`, the `two.colors` function:

```
library(fields)
two.colors(n=256, start='red', end='blue', middle='black')
```

[image]

Comment: @Roman Luštrik I used your suggestion and implemented this in my code. I got what I wanted, but the color bar is divided into sections. I have updated the question with the color bar received after implementing your suggestion. Is there a way to get a smooth gradient color bar? Also, for the labels of the color bar, is there a way that the code automatically distributes the number in the specified range in the labels. I have updated the code as well in the question.